# Adding the elements of an array to another array using perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Please, I want to know how to add the elements of an array to another one using perl.
And if there's a loop i can use to make a counter for the X array.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
$line = <STDIN>;
@array = split(/ /,$line);
print"$array[4]\n";
@X[0]=@array[4];
@X[1]=@array[4];
@X[2]=@array[4];
@X[3]=@array[4];
print @X;
```

Comment: You're going to have to expand on what you're trying to accomplish. Also - turn on `use strict; use warnings;` because that will tell you some errors in your code.

Comment: Okay thank you. Also i've turned on use strict; and use warnings; and they showed me lots of errors in my code which came in very handy.

Comment: Then add that error free code here after using strict & warnings, showing what you're trying to accomplish as @Sobrique has written already.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to how to add the elements of an array to another one using Perl.

If you have

```
my @data     = ( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
my @addition = ( 'x', 'y', 'z' );
```

then you can use `push` to add the contents of `@addition` to `@data` like this

```
push @data, @addition;
```

Now `@data` will contain `( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z' )`

The rest of your question is unclear

Comment: An excellent answer to a horrible question.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you want to read the fifth word from each input and then store in the array. You can refer my sample code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my  @x;
while(<STDIN>){
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split( /\s/, $line);
    push (@x, $array[4]);
    print "Your array: @x\n";
}
```

when running this code, if you input "`a b c d e`" it will store `e` to array `@x`, then if you continue typing the new line "`1 2 3 4 5`" value `5` will be stored into `@x` and so on. 
Ex:

```
a b c d e
Your array: e
1 2 3 4 5
Your array: e 5
one two three four five
Your array: e 5 five
```

Besides, I suggest you to check the condition at least 5 words for each line input as below:

```
if (scalar(@array) < 5){
    print "Require at least 5 words\n";
} else {
    push (@x, $array[4]);
    print "Your array: @x\n";
}
```